# Flask: Peewee model_to_dict helper not working

Tags: python, flask, peewee

i'm developing a little app for a University project and i need to json encode the result of a query to pass it to a js library, i've read elsewhere that i can use model_to_dict to accomplish that, but i'm getting this error

> AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute '_meta'

and i don't know why or what to do, does anyone know how to solve that?

I'm using python 2.7 and the last version of peewee

```
@app.route('/ormt')
def orm():
    doitch = Player.select().join(Nationality).where(Nationality.nation % 'Germany')
    return model_to_dict(doitch)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `doitch` is a `SelectQuery` instance it is not model, you have to call [`get()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SelectQuery.get)

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/ormt')
def orm():
    doitch = Player.select().join(Nationality).where(Nationality.nation % 'Germany')
    return jsonify(model_to_dict(doitch.get()))
```

Also you could use [dicts](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#retrieving-raw-tuples-dictionaries) method to get data as dict. This omits creation a whole model stuff.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/ormt')
def orm():
    doitch = Player.select().join(Nationality).where(Nationality.nation % 'Germany')
    return jsonify(doitch.dicts().get())
```

**edit**

As @lord63 pointed out, you cannot simply return dict, it must be a Flask response so convert it to jsonify.

**edit 2**

```
@app.route('/ormt')
def orm():
    doitch = Player.select().join(Nationality).where(Nationality.nation % 'Germany')
    # another query
    sth = Something.select()
    return jsonify({
        'doitch': doitch.dicts().get(),
        'something': sth_query.dicts().get()
    })
```

Comment: Ok, i did what you said trying both solutions and the initial problem is fixed, but now i get a **TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable** error; any idea about this? XD

Comment: @Vinz29 The problem is you return a dict, but in this situation, flask treats it as a wsgi app and try to convert it into a response. To solve this problem, you can try `jsonify(model_to_dict(doitch.get()))`.

Comment: perfect, now everything works, thank you both :D
one last thing, what if i want more than just one result? i tried execute but it doesn't work